# Difference between struct spell * spells; and spell * spells;

Tags: c++

I noticed that you can declare a pointer to a struct in two ways:

```
struct spell * spells;
```

and

```
spell * spells;
```

what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

In C, `struct` keyword **must be used** for declaring structure variables, but it is ***optional*** in C++.

For example, consider the following examples:

```
struct Foo
{
    int data;
    Foo* temp; // Error in C, struct must be there. Works in C++
};
int main()
{
    Foo a;  // Error in C, struct must be there. Works in C++
    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2**

```
struct Foo
{
    int data;
    struct Foo* temp;   // Works in both C and C++
};
int main()
{
    struct Foo a; // Works in both C and C++
    return 0;
}
```

In the above examples, `temp` is a data member that is a *pointer to non-const `Foo`*.